# How to find max limit of /proc/sys/fs/file-max

Tags: linux, kernel, lsof, tuning

I am running Jenkins with lots of jobs which require lots of open files so I have increased `file-max` limit to 3 million. It still hits 3 million sometimes so I am wondering how far I can go. Can I set `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` to 10 million?

How do I know what the hard limit of `file-max` is?

I am running `CentOS 7.7` (3.10.X kernel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel itself doesn’t impose any limitation on the value of `file-max`, beyond that imposed by its type ([`unsigned long`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.11/source/include/uapi/linux/fs.h#L97), so 4,294,967,295 on typical 32-bit systems, and 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 on typical 64-bit systems).

However each open file consumes [around one kilobyte of memory](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.11/source/fs/file_table.c#L386), so you’ll be limited by the amount of physical RAM installed; ten million open files would consume approximately ten gigabytes of memory. The kernel initialises `file-max` to 10% of the usable memory at boot, which means the “hard” limit on any given system is approximately ten times the default value.